# android mail sending, html formatting

Tags: android, html, email

I used this http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android for sending email in background. It's all working fine for sending the mail but I have another problem. I have strings that I want to be set in table in the email. I tried to make the email text like this "Name.... and so on. But when I receive the mail I have only the text i don't have formatted table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found it. Instead of set text I have to use setContent(mailText, "text/html; charset=utf-8");